# Display content between two dates?

Tags: posts, custom-field, metabox

I want to display a meta field between two dates, the admin can set the two dates via the custom fields.

How can i make such content show between the dates set?

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php <br />
 function filter_where($where = '') {<br/>
$where .= " AND post_date >= '1980-05-11' AND post_date <= '2011-05-11'";<br/ >
    return $where;</br>
  }<br/>
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');<br/>
query_posts($query_string);<br/>
while (have_posts()) :<br/>
      the_post();<br/>
      the_content();<br/>
endwhile;<br/>
?>
```

get meta data value and replace with the numeric date.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the help but the code will display the posts content on the certain dates, i want to display only a certain part in the post. Is this possible?

Comment: can you clear the question a little bit more??